# PowerPoint VBA Macro Gives Run Time Error 448: Named argument not found

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a PowerPoint 2010 VBA Macro to add a text box to every slide.
However, using the command from the [MSOffice documentation to create a text box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743980(v=office.14).aspx) doesn't even work.

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50).TextFrame _
.TextRange.Text = "Test Box"
```

This returns

```
Run-time error '448':
Named argument not found
```

Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Type:=` with `Orientation:=`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I notified MSDN so hopefully they'll fix it in the documentation.

Comment: It was correct in the VBA IDE (i.e. the Intellisense tooltip) which is where I found it.